# Openlayers 6 get geometry of a modified feature

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

How can I get the new feature geometry after its modification in Openlayers 6?  I'm listening to the **modifyend** event.

The source contains around 100 features. How can I do this?

```
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
       source: map_features_source
});

modify.on('modifyend', function (evt) {
       console.log(evt.target);
});

map.addInteraction(modify);
```

I tried this:

```
evt.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```

but it's not working as I have many elements in the array **evt.features.getArray()**. I need to find the one that was modified.

Comment: `evt.feattures[0],getGeometry()` - if features overlap it is possible to modify more than one feature in one operation, so you may need to loop through the array.

Comment: I have updated the question after having tried your solution.

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using?  Before 6.6.0 all features in the source were returned, which was not useful.

Comment: You are right, I was using version 6.1. Working now. You can write as the answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike described in comment, before the version 6.6.0 all features in the source were returned in the modifyend event. Just need to upgrade to that version minimum and this will match the modified feature:

```
evt.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```